# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: c#, sql-server, syntax-error

I am getting this syntax error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '('."

on the

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

line of code in my class file.

I have tried rewriting the entire class file and my button click method but somehow I am still doing it wrong.

Here is my code

Customer.cs:

```
    //properties
    public int memberId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string salutation { get; set; }
    public string telNo { get; set; }
    public string eMailAddr { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public DateTime birthDate { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }

    public int add()
    {
        string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NPCSConnectionString"].ToString();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Member (Name, Salutation, TelNo, EmailAddr, Password, BirthDate, City, Country" 
                                        + "VALUES(@memberID, @name, @salutation, @telNo, @eMailAddr, @password, @birthDate, @city, @country)", conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberID", memberId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salutation", salutation);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telNo", telNo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eMailAddr", eMailAddr);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthDate", birthDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", country);

        conn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
        return 0;
    }
```

The following code is used to call the add() method in a web form

```
            Customer objCustomer = new Customer();

            objCustomer.memberId = 8;
            objCustomer.name = txtName.Text;
            objCustomer.salutation = ddlSalutation.SelectedItem.Value;
            objCustomer.telNo = txtTelNo.Text;
            objCustomer.eMailAddr = txtEmail.Text;
            objCustomer.password = txtPassword.Text;
            objCustomer.birthDate = calBirthdate.SelectedDate;
            objCustomer.city = txtCity.Text;
            objCustomer.country = ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value;

            int errorCode = objCustomer.add();

            if (errorCode == 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("SuRegister.aspx");
            }
```

Comment: You are missing a ')' in your SQL query.

Comment: You are missing closing `)` in here: `INSERT INTO Member (Name, ..., City, Country`

Answer (score 3):

In your insert values you are passing a parameter called @memberID but you're not including it in the insert statement and you are missing a right bracket `")"`. Try the following:

```
"INSERT INTO Member (MemberId, Name, Salutation, TelNo, EmailAddr, Password, BirthDate, City, Country)" + "VALUES(@memberID, @name, @salutation, @telNo, @eMailAddr, @password, @birthDate, @city, @country)"
```

Comment: Yes but look at "INSERT INTO Member (Name,..." - where is the MemberID?

Comment: ok you're right. Could also be the auto incrementing primary key which doesn't need to be passed.

Comment: I'm guessing it's not autoincrement if he's passing it through as a parameter although you never know

Answer (score 2):

there is missing a `)` at the end of

```
INSERT INTO Member (Name, Salutation, TelNo, EmailAddr, Password, BirthDate, City, Country
```

Answer (score 2):

You miss one `)` in the query

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Member (Name, Salutation, TelNo, EmailAddr, Password, BirthDate, City, Country)" 
                                        + "VALUES(@memberID, @name, @salutation, @telNo, @eMailAddr, @password, @birthDate, @city, @country)", conn);
```